# ASP.net: Extending or Adding pieces to Existing BoundField

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Is it possible to add a property to the existing asp:BoundField control without creating a brand new instance to which I'd have to declare `<tst:BoundField></tst:BoundField>`?

If so, can someone provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You, you have to create a class that inherits from it and do it the way that you mentioned, or see if you could leverage the TemplateField or another column for what you are trying to do.

HTH.

Comment: Okay, so there is no way to actually add a property to the ASP:Boundfield?

Comment: As he said, you have to create your own class that inherits from it and then add the properties. Though this would require you to create your own GridView as well. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to extend the BoundField and TemplateFields to accept a FilterExpression for filtering criteria through a header UI. I have my own gridview, but was just wondering if there was a way to do this by using existing BoundField properties.